# Starting a web server using cmd.Command in a goroutine, process doesn't close when application is terminated

Tags: go

I am trying to spawn multiple commands concurrently from go, then close them all when the first task completes.

The problem is that sometimes when spawning a dotnet server and surnning my project with sudo, the spawned processes don't terminate when the application terminates.

Why is this happening and how do I get the processes to terminate?

Roughly this

```
func createCommand(command string) {
    var cmd *exec.Cmd
    cmd = exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", command)
    return cmd
}


func main() {
    commands := []string{
        "cd server1 && dotnet run", 
        "cd server2 && dotnet run",
        "sleep 10 && echo complete"
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    var cmds []*exec.Cmd

    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Process clean up")
        for _, cmd := range cmds {
            cmd.Process.Kill()
        }
    }()

    for _, command := range commands {
        cmd := createCommand(command)
        cmds = append(cmds, cmd)
        go func (c string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            c.Start()
            c.Wait()
        }(cmd)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the problem with sudo. But your code has these issues:

- You are spawning 3 goroutines but only adds 1 to the wait group, so maybe you made a mistake or your code actually only runs 1 command, other 2 will not be run. If you want 3, add 3 to the wait group.
- I cannot find cmd.Process.Kill() in go docs but I see the os.Process.Kill. However, it's recommend to use context to cancel the processes. With the context, your commands will certainly be terminated.

The code below demonstrates my idea:

```
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "context"
    "time"
)


func createCommand(ctx context.Context, command string) *exec.Cmd{
    return exec.CommandContext(ctx, "/bin/bash", "-c", command)
}


func main() {
    commands := []string{
        "sleep 1000000 && echo complete", 
        "sleep 1000000 && echo complete",
        "sleep 10 && echo complete",
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    var cmds []*exec.Cmd

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20 * time.Second)
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("Process clean up")
        cancel()
    }()

    for _, command := range commands {
    fmt.Printf("Create command %s\n", command)
        cmd := createCommand(ctx, command)
        cmds = append(cmds, cmd)
        go func (c *exec.Cmd, name string) {
        fmt.Printf("Process command %s\n", name)
            defer wg.Done()
            c.Start()
            c.Wait()
        fmt.Printf("Finish command %s\n", name)
        }(cmd, command)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

And the output is:

```
Create command sleep 1000000 && echo complete
Create command sleep 1000000 && echo complete
Create command sleep 10 && echo complete
Process command sleep 10 && echo complete
Finish command sleep 10 && echo complete
Process command sleep 1000000 && echo complete
Finish command sleep 1000000 && echo complete
Process command sleep 1000000 && echo complete
Finish command sleep 1000000 && echo complete
Process clean up
```